# AddHours to Linq Date result

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

Is it possible to add some hours to linq date result ?
something like this:

```
dim q = from a in somthing
        select new with {.x = a.date.AddHours(2)}
```

Comment: The code you've used as your example should work. What problem are you having with this code?

Answer (score 1):

If `a.date` is a `DateTime`, you can just do:

```
Dim q = from a in somthing
        select a.date.AddHours(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using linq-to-entities and you want the command to be executed on the database server try this:

```
Dim q = from a in something 
        select new with { .x = EdmFunctions.AddHours(a.date, 2) }
```

`EdmFunctions` is static class in `System.Data.Objects` namespace (part of `System.Data.Entity.dll`).

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in Ladislav's answer For LINQ-to-Entities you can use System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions.AddHours function (EntityFunctions is the name of the class not EdmFunctions as I know) which translates correctly to corresponding SQL.