# How to add hours to date using LINQ query?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, date, linq-to-sql

I need to get the last seven dates and add -4 hours to each date from my database

My SQL Query will be :

```
select DATEADD(hh, -4, [DateColumn]) 
from mydatabse.dbo.mytable
where DATEDIFF(dd, DATEADD(hh, -4, [DateColumn]), getdate()) between 1 and 7
group by DATEADD(hh, -4, [DateColumn])
```

Could anyone help me to convert this SQL query to LINQ ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AddHours to Linq Date result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466464/addhours-to-linq-date-result)

Comment: @Deepa Mani which version of `.Net Framework` are you using ?

Comment: Hi Mairaj 
I am using .NET 4.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you're using C#? Please see if the following fits your need:

```
using System.Data.Entity.SqlServer;

from a in mydatabase.mytable
let d = SqlFunctions.DateAdd("hh", -4, a.DateColumn)
let e = SqlFunctions.DateDiff("dd", d, SqlFunctions.GetDate())
where e >= 1 && e <= 7
group a by d into g
select g.Key;
```

Comment: Hi @ycsun

Thanks for your response

Comment: I have tried this but I am getting the below exception

Comment: Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime] DateAdd(System.String, System.Nullable`1[System.Double], System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Sorry!! I forgot to include the reference you have mentioned.Now the exception got cleared:-)

Comment: Awesome!!
It got Worked for me:-)
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't compiled it just try this

```
 var yourRecord =  DBContext.Table.Where(x => DbFunctions.AddDays(DateTime.Now, -7) <= x.YourDate && x.YourDate <= DateTime.Now).FirstOrDefault();
       yourRecord.YourDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(4);
```